# Docker container on Alpine Linux 3.7: Strange pid 1 not visible within the container's pid namespace

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

I am currently tracking a weird issue we are experiencing using dockerd `17.10.0-ce` on an `Alpine Linux 3.7` host. It seems for all the containers on this host, the process tree initiated as the entrypoint/command of the Docker image is NOT visible within the container itself. In comparison, on an Ubuntu host, the same image will have the process tree visible as PID 1.

Here is an example.

Run a container with an explicit known entrypoint/command:

```
% docker run -d --name testcontainer --rm busybox /bin/sh -c 'sleep 1000000'
```

Verify the processes are seen by dockerd properly:

```
% docker top testcontainer
PID                 USER                TIME                COMMAND
6729                root                0:00                /bin/sh -c sleep 1000000
6750                root                0:00                sleep 1000000
```

Now, start a shell inside that container and check the process list:

```
% docker exec -t -i testcontainer /bin/sh
/ # ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    6 root       0:00 /bin/sh
   12 root       0:00 ps -ef
```

As can be observed, our entrypoint command (/bin/sh -c 'sleep 1000000') is not visible inside the container itself. Even running `top` will yield the same results.

Is there something I am missing here? On an Ubuntu host with the same docker engine version, the results are as I would expect. Could this be related to Alpine's hardened kernel causing an issue with how the container PID space is separated?

Any help appreciated for areas to investigate.

-b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this problem is related to *grsecurity* module which the Alpine kernel implements. In this specific case, the `GRKERNSEC_CHROOT_FINDTASK` kernel setting is used to limit what processes can do outside of the chroot environment. This is controlled by the `kernel.grsecurity.chroot_findtask` sysctl variable.

From the `grsecurity` docs:

> kernel.grsecurity.chroot_findtask
>
> If you say Y here, processes inside a chroot will not be able to kill,
>   send signals with fcntl, ptrace, capget, getpgid, setpgid,  getsid, or
>   view any process outside of the chroot.  If the sysctl option is
>   enabled, a sysctl option with name "chroot_findtask" is created.

The only workaround I have found for now is to disable this flag as well as the `chroot_deny_mknod` and `chroot_deny_chmod` flags in order to get the same behaviour as with a non-grsecurity kernel.

```
kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_mknod=0
kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_chmod=0
kernel.grsecurity.chroot_findtask=0
```

Of course this is less than ideal since it bypasses and disables security features of the system but might be a valid workaround for a development environment.